# jquery ajax slow response in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am developing my site by Java. I am using jquery, ajax, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url : 'getWords.htm',
    type: 'post',
    async : false,
    data : {dataJSON : JSON.stringify(dataJSON)},
    success : function(words) {
        .....
    }
});
```

It is working well, but in Chrome it work slowly than Firefox, IE and Opera. In Chrome I have a little delay (about 0.8 sec). When I have four ajax query per one click it is really slow. How do I can fix it?

In firebug I see: sending 5ms, waiting 512ms, receiving 3ms,
but in other browsers all the fast.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say it works slower in Chrome, how much slower? 1ms? 10ms? 100ms?

Comment: It looks like your problem is in the server, not in the client.

Comment: @EswarRaj... 08sec I believe means 0.8sec

Comment: can you post a url with a test page?

Comment: @Sascha I can't, unfortunately. My site is not published yet.

Comment: @sochi "Waiting" means the time the server needs to respond (like gdoron presumes - it's probably a server-side issue)

Comment: @sochi I am having similar issue? Did it solve and how?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not loading the content of the `.post()` on a dynamic generated element try putting it inside `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready`, that had worked for me. Hope it helps!

**Update**

Being the `post()` fired with a click() event, the parent element needs to be ready. But you might win some time if you call the `post()` function outside your `$(document).ready` and save the results to a `javascript` variable. That will act as some kind of `initialValue` which you will need to update from the second time the user click on your element.

Comment: My event invoked when I press the button, how do I use window.onload? Sorry, I am new in javascript, I dont understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async: 'true'`.

This is the default and you shouldn’t switch to synchronous requests unless you have a very good reason to do so. First it will enable the browser to download files in parallel and second synchronous requests might block the browser thread.

By the way: *"As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated."* (from [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docu)

Comment: "I need 'async: false' in my case, but if I specify 'async: true', I have delay too.

Comment: Not sure if they updated the docs between this response and now, but that deprecation isn't true. It's only deprecated if you're using the $.Deferred object returned from the $.ajax call, since it won't work in that case: "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated;"

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me a while ago, and the response time was different for each browser when calling an AJAX, POST or GET. It turned out to be a huge amount of data that I was passing from the url, "getWords.htm" in your case. A couple of questions that could help to determine what's wrong in your case:

1. How much data are you sending back and what's the format? Try
   JSON and parse it in the "SUCCESS" function to generate the HTML
   code/page.
2. How many DOM objects are you trying to generate in one
   shot? It helps a lot to parse whatever you need on the fly, which is easy to
   do once you have the JSON on the client side and generate the HTML
   from there dynamically.

Answer (score -3):

sometimes it is better to use jquery on the machine and not the one stored in google.
depends on the Internet connection you have

Local

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

Api from google

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The OP problem is with an ajax call, not the loading of jquery.